# How to prevent SQL injection when the statement has a dynamic table name?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, oracle12c

I am having code something like this.

```
   final PreparedStatement stmt = connection
                .prepareStatement("delete from " + fullTableName
                    + " where name= ?");
   stmt.setString(1, addressName);
```

Calculation of `fullTableName` is something like:

```
 public String getFullTableName(final String table) {
    if (this.schemaDB != null) {
        return this.schemaDB + "." + table;
    }
    return table;
 }
```

Here `schemaDB` is the name of the environment(which can be changed over time) and `table` is the table name(which will be fixed).

Value for `schemaDB` is coming from an `XML` file which makes the query vulnerable to SQL injection.

**Query:** I am not sure how the table name can be used as a prepared statement(like the `name` used in this example), which is the 100% security measure against SQL injection.

Could anyone please suggest me, what could be the possible approach to deal with this?

**Note:** We can be migrated to DB2 in future so the solution should compatible with both Oracle and DB2(and if possible database independent).

Comment: If you control the xml file (i.e., it's not something users can change/provide) you should be ok.

Comment: You cannot bind a table name in a `PreparedStatement`, either you must accept the XML files are valid (you could potentially validate the table name) or hardcode all valid tables and resolve it that way.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, Yes this is what I am planning to do at last(to validate the table name, before appending it to query). But I am not 100% sure if it will be the best approach to prevent SQL injection here.

Comment: Make it yet safer : prebuild a list of full statements ("DELETE FROM table_1 WHERE name= ?", "DELETE FROM table_2 WHERE name = ?", etc... for all your tables. Put them in a (Hash)Map. And do no validate that the table name is correct before concatenating strings. Instead, select one of the prebuilt, inherently safe, statements based on the user-generated entry. That way, nothing user-generated gets concatenated to your statement. Only developer, prebuilt, queries hit the DB.

Comment: @GPI, By validating the table name what I meant is to check if the string is only containing alphanumeric characters(as the table names in my project are having only alphanumeric characters). Here I can not be sure about exact table name.

Comment: You can ask Oracle for all existing user table name... ? Surely your app is not that dynamic that it does not known the name of its own tables, especially if those tables are operated by the process you describe ? (It can be, it's just really unusual). Like : whatever the table, I know it has a "name" column ? Sounds weird.

Comment: @GPI, my apologies for the obscureness and thanks for answering. I have edited the question for the more clear picture.

Comment: @Gaurav : i've added a way to check existing table names by querying Oracle for them beforehand (inside step 1).

Comment: Can you use Oracle-provided functions? In PL/SQL I would validate names with DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME, can you take advantage of it from your code? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_assert.htm#BABHIEBA

Comment: @GPI, could you please suggest something for this question "https://stackoverflow.com/q/49512493/6242317"

Comment: @Gaurav seems to me the first answer is a correct one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JDBC, sort of unfortunately, does not allow you to make the table name a bound variable inside statements. (It has its reasons for this).

So you can not write, or achieve this kind of functionnality :

```
connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ? where id=?", "TUSERS", 123);
```

And have `TUSER` be bound to the table name of the statement.

Therefore, your only safe way forward is to validate the user input. The safest way, though, is not to validate it and allow user-input go through the DB, because from a security point of view, you can always count on a user being smarter than your validation.
Never trust a dynamic, user generated String, concatenated inside your statement.

So what is a safe validation pattern ?

### Pattern 1 : prebuild safe queries

1) Create all your valid statements once and for all, in code.

```
Map<String, String> statementByTableName = new HashMap<>();
statementByTableName.put("table_1", "DELETE FROM table_1 where name= ?");
statementByTableName.put("table_2", "DELETE FROM table_2 where name= ?");
```

If need be, this creation itself can be made dynamic, with a `select * from ALL_TABLES;` statement. `ALL_TABLES` will return all the tables your SQL user has access to, and you can also get the table name, and schema name from this.

2) Select the statement inside the map

```
String unsafeUserContent = ...
String safeStatement = statementByTableName.get(usafeUserContent);
conn.prepareStatement(safeStatement, name);
```

See how the `unsafeUserContent` variable never reaches the DB.

3) Make some kind of policy, or unit test, that checks that all you `statementByTableName` are valid against your schemas for future evolutions of it, and that no table is missing.

### Pattern 2 : double check

You can 1) validate that the user input is indeed a table name, using an injection free query (I'm typing pseudo sql code here, you'd have to adapt it to make it work cause I have no Oracle instance to actually check it works) :

```
select * FROM 
    (select schema_name || '.' || table_name as fullName FROM all_tables)
WHERE fullName = ?
```

And bind your fullName as a prepared statement variable here. If you have a result, then it is a valid table name. Then you can use this result to build a safe query.

### Pattern 3

It's sort of a mix between 1 and 2.
You create a table that is named, e.g., "TABLES_ALLOWED_FOR_DELETION", and you statically populate it with all tables that are fit for deletion.

Then you make your validation step be

```
conn.prepareStatement(SELECT safe_table_name FROM TABLES_ALLOWED_FOR_DELETION WHERE table_name = ?", unsafeDynamicString);
```

If this has a result, then you execute the safe_table_name. For extra safety, this table should not be writable by the standard application user.

I somehow feel the first pattern is better.

Comment: It was the nice explanation and had solved my issue but suddenly come to know that we can be migrated to DB2 after some time, so the code should be compatible to both of the databases DB2 and Oracle(It will be more efficient if we can make it database independent). if you can add any further comment, it will help me in finding the solution.

Comment: The first pattern has nothing DB dependant. The second does, because `all_tables` is Oracle specific. I think you won't find a portable "pattern2" implementation. I'll add a 3rd variant.

Comment: To fetch the user created table, `schemaDB` name is required, which is coming from an `XML` file. I am not sure if we can have a general query instead of ("CREATOR || '.' || name as fullTableName FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES" for DB2 and "select owner || '.' || table_name as fullTableName FROM all_tables;" for Oracle).

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid attack by checking your table name using regular expression:

```
if (fullTableName.matches("[_a-zA-Z0-9\\.]+")) {
    final PreparedStatement stmt = connection
                .prepareStatement("delete from " + fullTableName
                    + " where name= ?");
    stmt.setString(1, addressName);
}
```

It's impossible to inject SQL using such a restricted set of characters.

Also, we can escape any quotes from table name, and safely add it to our query:

```
fullTableName = StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(fullTableName);
final PreparedStatement stmt = connection
            .prepareStatement("delete from " + fullTableName
                + " where name= ?");
stmt.setString(1, addressName);
```

StringEscapeUtils comes with Apache's commons-lang library.

Comment: Yeah. But is it not possible, on at least some DBs other than Oracle, to have table names with Diacritics ? Dollar signs or dashes whatever ? Cyrillic / Chinese / Japanese / Whatever names ?  Honnest question, that would change this answer's context of validity.

Comment: @GPI, this is an answer for most generic cases, the idea is to restrict the characters.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best approach is to create a set of possible table names and check for existance in this set before creating query.

```
Set<String> validTables=.... // prepare this set yourself

    if(validTables.contains(fullTableName))
    {
       final PreparedStatement stmt = connection
                    .prepareStatement("delete from " + fullTableName
                        + " where name= ?");

    //and so on
    }else{
       // ooooh you nasty haker!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table MYTAB(n number);
insert into MYTAB values(10);
commit;
select * from mytab;

N
10

create table TABS2DEL(tname varchar2(32));
insert into TABS2DEL values('MYTAB');
commit;
select * from TABS2DEL;

TNAME
MYTAB

create or replace procedure deltab(v in varchar2)
is

    LvSQL varchar2(32767);
    LvChk number;

begin
    LvChk := 0;
    begin
        select count(1)
          into LvChk
          from TABS2DEL
         where tname = v;

         if LvChk = 0 then
             raise_application_error(-20001, 'Input table name '||v||' is not a valid table name');
         end if;


    exception when others
              then raise;
    end;

    LvSQL := 'delete from '||v||' where n = 10';
    execute immediate LvSQL;
    commit;

end deltab;

begin
deltab('MYTAB');
end;

select * from mytab;
```

no rows found

```
begin
deltab('InvalidTableName');
end;

ORA-20001: Input table name InvalidTableName is not a valid table name ORA-06512: at "SQL_PHOYNSAMOMWLFRCCFWUMTBQWC.DELTAB", line 21
ORA-06512: at "SQL_PHOYNSAMOMWLFRCCFWUMTBQWC.DELTAB", line 16
ORA-06512: at line 2
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, wouldn't TAB2DEL be better named "TABLES_ALLOWED_TO_BE_DELETED" ? It's a static table right ? If not, I do not really see what is the way you call your procedure from application code..