# Hibernate : How to prevent SQL injection when the collection elements needs to check with `like` operator?

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-injection, oracle12c

I am having a `query` something like this.

```
StringBuilder sbQry = new StringBuilder();
sbQry.append("select * from tableName where 1=1");
if(!myCollection.isEmpty()){
    sbQry.append("  and (");
        for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.size(); i++) {
            final String module = myCollection.get(i);
            sbQry.append("column = '" + module
                    + "' or column like 'J_'||'"
                    + module.replaceAll("-", "%") + "'");
            if (!(i == (myCollection.size() - 1))) {
                sbQry.append(" or ");
            }
        }
        sbQry.append(") ");
 }
```

**Here this query `sbQry` is vulnerable to `SQLInjection` because of `myCollection` is coming from the external source.**

In case my collection elements would be comparing based on `=` operator then I use prepared statement, something like:

```
sbQry.append(column in (:collection));
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sbQry.toString());
query.setParameterList("collection",myCollection);
```

Could anyone please suggest me how can I prevent the SQL injection in this case.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @BillKarwin what is the issue with that?

Comment: @PrasadReddy, The variable `mycollection` may contain a single-quote character. The risk of SQL injection is exactly the same when using `LIKE` as with any other case of interpolating a variable into an SQL query.

Comment: query.createQuery("select at from Class where lower(column) LIKE lower(:searchKeyword)");
query.setParameter("searchKeyword", "%"+searchKeyword+"%");

Comment: @PrasadReddy, Yes, exactly, one should use bound parameters to protect against SQL injection when using `LIKE`, just like with any other use of a variable. It's just not true that "you don't need to bother." That gives the wrong idea that code can use the unsafe method of string concatenation of variables directly into SQL queries. Also, it is not correct that bound parameters are concatenated into the query. The point of bound parameters is that they are *not* combined with the query string.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions @BillKarwin. Need your small help in understanding this select * from table where ""="". Why it returns entire data?

Comment: @PrasadReddy, `"" = ""` is always true, just like `1 = 1` is always true.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill. As you said parameter binding  with sql queries  prevents sql injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To protect against SQL injection, you should use bound parameters, not string interpolation.

```
StringBuilder sbQry = new StringBuilder();
List<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
sbQry.append("select * from tableName");
if(!myCollection.isEmpty()){
    sbQry.append(" where ");
    int size = myCollection.size;
    List<String> terms = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        final String module = myCollection.get(i);
        terms.add("column = ? or column like ?");
        params.add(module);
        params.add("J_" + module.replaceAll("-", "%"));
    }
    sbQry.append(String.join(" or ", terms));
}

Query q = sess.createQuery(sbQry);
int size = params.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    q.setString(i, params[i]);
}
```

I have not tested the above code, but it should give you the general idea.

Using bound parameters instead of string concatenation is a safe way to protect against SQL injection, and it also makes code easier to write and easier to read.

Also using ArrayList for the terms, and `String.join()`, means you don't have to fuss with `1=1` or special conditional code for the beginning or end of the series of terms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will make a test tomorrow and will let you know.